# How can i render partial with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to add AJAX to my blog.
And i want to make post, edit and delete comments using ajax.
For example, to post a comment, I used:

```js
$(".comment<%=@comment.parent_id %>").append('<%= j render partial:'comments/comment', locals: {comment: @comment} %>');
```

But due to the fact that I have nesting, it was not displayed as I would like.
All comments I have are in _comment.html.erb. 
Can I render a partial without reloading the page using jquery?
And is this the right approach?

Comment: Partials are views, but you typically want to return JSON on ajax requests, and update the dom with the data returned. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: You can render a partial without reloading the page using ajax if needed. Section 4.1 of the guide that @lacostenycoder linked to shows a nice simple example of how to do that in rails, and you can modify that quite easily to handle nested resources.

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already wrote, all the comments I had were in the partial. And because of the nesting, I could not just add a new comment using the `append` function. Therefore, I just update the partial on the page, without reloading the page as follows:

```
$(".comments").replaceWith("<div class='comments'><%= j nested_comments @post.comments.arrange(order: :created_at)%>")
```